# How set a Coap Observer that listen for response

Tags: java, eclipse, coap, californium

I'm working with californium library to use Coap protocol in my eclipse project.
I have sent a request to a server Coap.
Now i have set on this server a different end point to give response.
How can i implement an observer that listen and wait to receive this response ?

Answer (score 0):

The response to an observe request must always come from the same endpoint as the request was sent to. A message from a different endpoint on that server (that is, from a different IP address or from a different port) would not be recognized by the client.

Comment: I want that many clients can send a request at my server and i want that this don't block my system ... I'm using spring and i operate on the same context. how can i implement a listener for response ?

Comment: If you don't want to change the endpoint in the middle of the observation, you may want to phrase your question more clearly ("have set on this server a different end point to give response" leads one to believe that). It'd help to have concrete code and a complete description of your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty unsure, If I understand your question.

> how can i implement a listener for response ?

On the server side? To prepare the response?

Then the intention is to override CoapResource.handleGET.